# Python property to restrict access

Tags: python, properties

I have the following code :

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, dx = 1):
       self._dx = dx
    def get_dx(self):
       return self._dx

    dx = property(get_dx,None,None)

c = C()
print c.dx
c.dx = 42
print c.dx  # this shows 42
```

This should work [(see here)](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#more-on-properties-example). However, it is not and my questions are as follows :

1. Is it at all possible to restrict users from doing : `c.dx = 42` ?
2. If so, how? (my intention is to make read-only attributes, I know that there is always a way to hack around it, but I just want to prevent the standard c.dx = val from working)

Comment: Note that `c.dx` is entirely different from `c._dx`. Also note that python is not java.

Comment: I understand that c.dx isnt the same as c._dx, but what do you mean by "note that python is not java"? I understand that private variables dont exist in python the same way they do in java, but which part of the code made you say that? :P

Comment: I suppose I'm just questioning the point behind making it impossible to do `c.dx=42`. (But indeed the answer you accepted is the right way to do it!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`property` with no setter defined is read-only. The only reason this might not work is that you're using Python 2 and defined an old-style class. Remember to *always* derive from `object` in Python 2.x:

```
class C(object):
    @property
    def dx(self):
        return self._dx

    def __init__(self, dx = 1):
        self._dx = dx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class C:
    def __init__(self, dx = 1):
       self.__dx = dx
    def get_dx(self):
       return self.__dx

    dx = property(get_dx,None,None)

c = C()
print c.get_dx()
print c.__dx  # this raise error
```

Source:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Comment: Why the double underscore? Does that not make python mangle the namespace? (or is that intended maybe?)

Comment: There is no reason to use name mangling, and if your example access would be like OP's (use the property, not an explicit getter and the underlying attribute), it would be exactly the same.

Comment: @Arnab Datta Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.